# Fourier transform of continuous-mode quantum creation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, conventions, fourier-transform

As I was reading "The quantum theory of light" by Rodney Loudon, I reached the following part that defines the relationship between time-domain and frequency-domain continuous-mode annihilation operators (page 239):

> ...it is useful to **define** Fourier transformed operators by
> $$\hat{a}(t) = (2\pi)^{-1/2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}d\omega \hat{a}(\omega)\exp(-i\omega t)$$

That is the time-domain annihilation operator is the Fourier transform of its frequency-domain counterpart, i.e. $\hat{a}(t)=\mathcal{F}\lbrace \hat{a}(\omega)\rbrace$.

The above relationship results in the following relationship for creation operators
$$\hat{a}^\dagger(t) = (2\pi)^{-1/2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}d\omega \hat{a}(\omega)^\dagger\exp(+i\omega t)$$

My question is that

> Is this definition, only a matter of notation or there is a physical argument and meaning behind the expression $\hat{a}(t)=\mathcal{F}\lbrace \hat{a}(\omega)\rbrace$?
>
> Can we **define** the Fourier transformed operators using the creation operators instead of annihilation operators without any bad physical consequences?
> (i.e. can we  define $$\hat{a}^\dagger(t) = (2\pi)^{-1/2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}d\omega \hat{a}^\dagger(\omega)\exp(-i\omega t),$$ so that $\hat{a}^\dagger(t)=\mathcal{F}\lbrace \hat{a}^\dagger(\omega)\rbrace$)

P.S. The only difference that I've realized is that using the first definition, the frequency-domain wavepackets are the Fourier transform of its time-domain counterpart, i.e. $$\hat{a}(t):=\mathcal{F}\lbrace \hat{a}(\omega)\rbrace\Rightarrow\xi(\omega)=\mathcal{F}\lbrace \xi(t)\rbrace,$$ while it is vise a versa for the second definition, $$\hat{a}^\dagger(t):=\mathcal{F}\lbrace \hat{a}^\dagger(\omega)\rbrace\Rightarrow\xi(t)=\mathcal{F}\lbrace \xi(\omega)\rbrace$$
where $\xi(t)$ and $\xi(\omega)$ are the time-domain and frequency-domain wavepackets.
$$\hat{a}^\dagger_{\xi}= \int d\omega\xi(\omega)\hat{a}^\dagger(\omega) = \int dt\xi(t)\hat{a}^\dagger(t) $$

Comment: Isn't this just a notation thing? If you define $\hat{a}^\dagger(t)$ as the fourier transform of the creation operator, then it is not the same thing as the adjoint of the previously defined $\hat{a}(t)$ of course.

Comment: @Rescy_ Thank you for your comment. I support the idea that this is only a convention. However, one of my collogues at the university disagrees and argues that this notation might have a strong physical meaning and that changing the notation would be physically incorrect. I asked this question to ensure that I understood this subject currectly.